# How to convert a nested list to a 2d array

Tags: java

I need to convert a nested list of Double to a double[][]. I have tried using the code below, but the issue is how to convert to the primitive double. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
double[][] matrix = new double[listReturns.size()][];
    int i = 0;
    for (List<Double> nestedList : listReturns) {
        matrix[i++] = nestedList.toArray(new Double[nestedList.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use streams:

```
double[][] mat =
    listReturns.stream() // Stream<List<Double>>
               .map(list -> list.stream() 
                                .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                .toArray()) // map each inner List<Double> to a double[]
               .toArray(double[][]::new); // convert Stream<double[]> to a double[][]
```

Comment: Just be warned that if this is for a college homework, and you give this answer, you better be prepared to know EVERYTHING about streams.

Comment: It solved the problem. This is not homework. Many thanks.